# Input validation within strings and how to use a flag to catch it

Tags: c++

I am trying to validate the users input, if they input anything besides `red`, `yellow` or `blue`. Any other input for example `white` should result in an error message for the user.

I have even tried to put an `else if` statement to catch it, and it does, but when I use `mimir.io` (how my class submits code, and gets checked automatically) I get an output that does not match my output. It's very frustrating, but I did try to cheat the code a little because I know the desired response.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//Variables
std::string red = "red";
std::string blue = "blue";
std::string yellow = "yellow";
std::string white = "white";
std::string primaryColor1 = "";
std::string primaryColor2 = "";

//Input
int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter a primary color (red, blue, yellow):" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> primaryColor1;
    std::cout << "Enter a different primary color (red, blue, yellow):" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> primaryColor2;

//Processing and Output
    if (primaryColor1 == primaryColor2) {
        std::cout << "You entered invalid colors" << std::endl;
    } else if ( primaryColor1 == red && primaryColor2 == white) {
        std::cout << "You entered invalid colors" << std::endl;
    }else if (primaryColor1 == red && primaryColor2 == blue) {
        std::cout << primaryColor1 <<" and " << primaryColor2 << " make purple" << std::endl;
    } else if (primaryColor1 == red && primaryColor2 == yellow) {
        std::cout << primaryColor1 <<" and " << primaryColor2 << " make orange" << std::endl;
    } else if (primaryColor1 == blue && primaryColor2 == yellow) {
        std::cout << primaryColor1 <<" and " << primaryColor2 << " make green" << std::endl;
    }  else if (primaryColor1 == blue && primaryColor2 == red) {
        std::cout << primaryColor1 <<" and " << primaryColor2 << " make purple" << std::endl;
    } else if (primaryColor1 == yellow && primaryColor2 == red) {
        std::cout << primaryColor1 <<" and " << primaryColor2 << " make orange" << std::endl;
    } else  {
        std::cout << primaryColor1 <<" and " << primaryColor2 << " make green" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want the user to input `red` then `white`, and then get the error message: `"You entered invalid colors"`

Comment: A much more simpler implementation is to create a `std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string>`, where the pair of strings are the two colors, and the data is the final color.  That would skip all of the `if` / `else` stuff.

Comment: First, [here is an example of what I mentioned](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6983be6604db459).  Second [cannot duplicate your error](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5e0b17a9c3f699d)

Comment: My error will not be duplicated which is the problem its the site where I input the code.

Comment: @TurgorPressure so, exactly, what do you expect us to do to solve your problem? You did not even tell us what kind of error your are facing off

Comment: I don't know what `mimir.io` is.  Maybe you should contact the persons who maintain that about your error.  Or you could try the first method I posted with the map, just to see what happens.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion. I get this error when I input my code to my [class code checking thing]. The top is what I am getting, and the bottom is what I am supposed to get. I am asking if there is another way around this issue while still using if/else if statements.
 

< Enter a primary color (red, blue, yellow):
< Enter a different primary color (red, blue, yellow):
< Red and white make green

---

> Enter a primary color (red, blue, yellow): 
> Enter a different primary color (red, blue, yellow): 
> You entered invalid colors

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your code, there are 3 valid colors:

`red`, `blue`, `yellow`

There are 4 possible outputs, depending on provided colors:

- `blue` + `yellow` / `yellow` + `blue` -> `purple`
- `red` + `yellow` / `yellow` + `red` -> `orange`
- `blue` + `yellow` / `yellow` + `blue` -> `green`
- Any other color or combination of colors -> `invalid`.

Your code doesn't apply these rules as any invalid user input that is neither `(primaryColor1 == primaryColor2)` or `(primaryColor1 == red && primaryColor2 == white)` will fall into the final `else` which produces `... and ... make green`.

Here's a pseudo-code of if-else statements that comply to the rules:

- **if** `blue` **and** `yellow` **or** `yellow` **and** `blue` -> `purple`
- **else if** `red` **and** `yellow` **or** `yellow` **and** `red` -> `orange`
- **else if** `blue` **and** `yellow` **or** `yellow` **and** `blue` -> `green`
- **else** `invalid`